# DataTables can't submit AJAX form to PHP when resized to mobile

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am having an issue when submitting form data using AJAX on resized screen to mobile. All works fine when you resize the page to desktop.

I am using jQuery DataTables and I have a button on each row to edit the form. All works fine when the page is not resized and the DataTable is in full screen, As soon as I resize the page to mobile and tablets, the DataTable creates an green "plus" icon on the left to expand the table but when I click on the edit button, I am getting an error `Invalid Ajax Request` and in the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Again this works on large screen sizes but not on mobile and tablets.

I am using PHP MVC, here is the code:

My jQuery function:

```
$(function () {
    $("form#editEmailTemplate").on('submit', function (e) {
        var postData = $(this).serialize();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        var formMethod = $(this).attr("method");
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: formMethod,
            data: postData,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            scriptCharset: "UTF-8",
            ContentType: 'html',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var returnedData = JSON.parse(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < returnedData.length; i++) {
                    $('#response').empty();
                    $("#DataTableEmails_wrapper").hide();
                    $("#updateEmailTemplate").show();

                    $('#emailid').val(returnedData[0][i].emailid);
                    $('.emailtitle').text(returnedData[0][i].title);
                    $('#emailsubject').val(returnedData[0][i].subject);
                    $('#emailtext').val(returnedData[0][i].textmessage);
                    $('#emailhtml').val(returnedData[0][i].htmlmessage);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#response').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Something went wrong !!! . Email tremplate has NOT  been  selected</div>');
                setTimeout(fade_out, 10000);
                function fade_out() {
                    $("#response").fadeOut().empty();
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    });
});
```

And the HTML form is:

```
<form class="ui segment error" role="form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" 
    action="mail/editEmailTemplate/" id="editEmailTemplate">
    <input type="hidden" name="emailid" value="' . $value['emailid'] . '">
    <input type="image" name="submit" value="" src = "' . ICO . 'system/configure.png" 
        width="20" height="auto" title = "' . lang('BTN_EDIT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_TOOLTIP') . '"/>
</form>
```

The form has same structure and data on all screen sizes so hasn't change on resize.

Comment: Check for tags all are closed properly?

Comment: From your description, it seems that you're using Responsive extension for DataTables. Please show your DataTables initialization code and the event handler for "Edit" button since *when I click on the edit button, I am getting an error*.

Comment: Thanks Sherapy

The dataTable initialization is :

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#DataTableEmails').dataTable({
    //        serverSide: true,
    responsive: true,
    "jQueryUI": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: [0],
        orderData: [0, 1]
      }, {
        targets: [1],
        orderData: [1, 0]
      }, {
        targets: [2],
        orderData: [2, 0]
      }, {
        targets: [3],
        orderData: [3, 0]
      },
      {className: "dt-center", "targets": [0, 3]}
    ]
  });

////The above jQuery function is here/////////////////////

 });

Comment: I am using form submit method to post form data . It seems on mobile resized the datatable does not call the function  `code` "$("form#editEmailTemplate").on('submit', function (e) {" `code`  but it call it on desktop size. The controller gets the Id correct on post  all the time because is hidden field

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your formURL is returning with an HTML formatted 404 not found. When it does this it will contain

```
<html></html>
```

which isn't valid javascript or if that file is PHP and there's an error in it it's also responding with an HTML format leading with '<' in the response. Since this isn't a valid response it will break when encountered.

Comment: This doesn't explain that the code works on on large screens. This should be the comment and not the answer, too much guess work.

Comment: The controller gets the id on post either way the only problem is when resized to mobile  the function "$("form#editEmailTemplate").on('submit', function (e) {}"   doesn't get called bit works on larger screen. I have also tested      by creating "demo" function totally separate and assigned an Id to the button  but Jquery doesn't  respond at all.

Comment: the URL is correct because uses same URL for all screen sizes, It is the same form. The URL hits the controller and gets the Id the only problem is on mobile size does not call the ajax function which is same for all screen and works on other sizes,